# Objective-C Sort String Date Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have an array which consists of dates but as `NSString`. How do I sort it descending?

EDIT : I Ended up by tweaking my code to use NSDate as using other methods won't work in my case

Comment: You have NSArray of string ??

Comment: Yes , And I've triend the caseInsensitiveCompare: method but it returns ascending order not descending

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use NSDate * ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `sortedArrayUsingFunction`, consider the bellow example

```
NSString *str1 = @"03-07-2012";
NSString *str2 = @"01-07-2012";
NSString *str3 = @"02-07-2012";


NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:str1, str2, str3, nil];
arr = [arr sortedArrayUsingFunction:dateSort context:nil];


//The date sort function
NSComparisonResult dateSort(NSString *s1, NSString *s2, void *context) {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    NSDate *d1 = [formatter dateFromString:s1];
    NSDate *d2 = [formatter dateFromString:s2];

    return [d1 compare:d2]; // ascending order
    return [d2 compare:d1]; // descending order
}
```

Comment: Or following the same thought, since caseInsensitiveCompare: returns the expected results but in ascending order you could skip formatting the strings as dates and just return [s2 caseInsensitiveCompare:s1]

Comment: but it wont work on strings like 1-july-2012, 1-jun-2012

Comment: Hence the introduction of my reply. But in that particular example this would actually work :)

Answer (score 2):

Covert NSString date to NSDate object and than sort array based on date

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr]; 

NSComparisonResult dateSort(NSString *s1, NSString *s2, void *context) {
    NSDate *d1 = [NSDate dateWithString:s1];
    NSDate *d2 = [NSDate dateWithString:s2];
    return [d1 compare:d2];
}

NSArray *sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingFunction:dateSort context:nil];
```